# Using JSoup CSS selectors

Tags: java, css-selectors, web-crawler, jsoup

I am trying to use [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) to scrape some content off of a website. Here is some sample HTML content from the page I am interested in:

```
<div class="sep_top shd_hdr pb2 luna">
    <div class="KonaBody" style="padding-left:0px;">
        <div class="lunatext results_content frstluna">
            <div class="luna-Ent">
                <div class="header">
                <div class="body">
                    <div class="pbk">
                        <div id="rltqns">
                    <div class="pbk">
                        <span class="pg">
                            <span id="hotword">
                                <span id="hotword">Fizz</span>
                            </span>
                        </span>
                        <div class="luna-Ent">
                        <div class="luna-Ent">
                        <div class="luna-Ent">
                        <div class="luna-Ent">
                    </div>
                    <div class="pbk">
                        <span class="sectionLabel">
                        <span class="pg">
                            <span id="hotword">
                                <span id="hotword">Buzz</span>
                            </span>
                        </span>
                        <span class="pg">
                            <span id="hotword">
                                <span id="hotword">Foo</span>
                            </span>
                        </span>
                        <span class="pg">
                            <span id="hotword">
                                <span id="hotword">Bar</span>
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                <div class="tail">
            </div>
            <div class="rcr">
        <!-- ... rest of content omitted for brevity -->
```

I am interested in obtaining a list of all the `hotwords` in the page (so "Fizz", "Buzz", "Foo" and "Bar"). **But I can't just query for `hotword`, because they use the `hotword` class all over the place to decorate lots of different elements.** Specifically, I need all the `hotwords` that exist inside a `pbk pg hotword` element. Note that pbks can contain 0+ pgs, and pgs can contain 0+ hotwords, and hotwords can contain 1+ other hotwords. I have the following code:

```
// Update, per PShemo:
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://somesite.example.com").get();

System.out.println("Starting to crawl...");

// Get the document's .pbk elements.
Elements pbks = doc.select(".pbk");

List<String> hotwords = new ArrayList<String>();

System.out.println(String.format("Found %s pbks.", pbks.size()));
int pbkCount = 0;
for(Element pbk : pbks) {
    pbkCount++;

    // Get the .pbk element's .pg elements.
    for(Element pg : pbk.getElementsByClass("pg")) {
        System.out.println(String.format("PBK #%s has %s pgs.", pbkCount, pbk.getElementsByClass("pg").size()));
        Element hotword = pg.getElementById("hotword");

        System.out.println("Adding hotword: " + hotword.text());
        hotwords.add(hotword.text());
    }
}
```

Running that code produces the following output:

```
Starting to crawl...
Found 3 pbks.
```

I am either not using the JSoup API correctly, or not using the right selectors, or both. Any thoughts as to where I'm going awry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `getElementsByClass` then you don't need to add `.` before it, just use class name like `getElementsByClass("pg")`, not `getElementsByClass(".pg")`

Same goes to `getElementById`. Don't add `#` before `id` value. Just use `getElementById("hotword")`.

Also it seems that your `div`s with `pbk` class are nested so `getElementsByClass` could give you duplicate results.

---

After knowing what page you are trying to parse you can do it with one selector. Try maybe this way

```
for (Element element:doc.select("div.body div.pbk span.pg")){
    System.out.println(element.text());
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Pschemo (+1) - that helped a little but now it's telling me that there are no hotwords in the document, which I know is false. The URL I'm actually trying to hit is [http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/quick?s=t](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/quick?s=t), and I'm trying to accumulate a list of all the different "word types" (adjective, noun, verb) a particular word is. For example, on that link, the word "quick" is 3 different types: adjective, noun and adverb. How could I tweak my JSoup selectors to obtain a List<String> with the values "adjective", "noun" and "verb" in it?

Comment: @TicketMonster I updated my code a little. It seems to work as you want. I came up with this solution after seeing HTML code that JSoup get from that site (you can see it with `System.out.println(doc);`).

Answer (score 0):

```
Elements hotwords = document.select("#hotwords");

for (Element hotword : hotwords){
    String word = hotword.getText();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @William Falcon, but that doesn't work either. The `hotword` variable has a size of 0.